# Microsoft Graph API delta for externally shared folders

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, azure-data-lake

A user in another organisation shares a folder with me.
I can see the shared files using the following endpoint:

```html
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/sharedWithMe?allowexternal=true
```

Is it possible to list the changes in this folder using `delta` as you would do for a drive in my organisation?

For instance, to show the changes in my drive, I would use

```html
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/delta
```

However because the shared folder is in a drive outside my organisation, if I try to query it using

```html
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}
```

I get a `404 - ItemNotFound`

Is this something possible to do?

If not, any other way I could see the changes made in a shared folder so that I could for example keep a synced copy of the folder in Azure Storage?

Comment: Have you used the call something like this `/drives/{drive-id}/root/delta`?

Comment: Yes @Shiva-MSFTIdentity, still getting ```ItemNotFound```. Any other idea?

Comment: We are looking into this.

Comment: Thank you @Shiva-MSFTIdentity, much appreciated

Comment: Any news on this @Shiva-MSFTIdentity?

Comment: Not yet, still waiting on the PG. Will update the thread once I get an update.

Comment: @ShivaKeshavVarma, do you have any update on this?